# Multiple Loops on a Page Without Duplicates

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have tried many different versions of this and nothing seems to be working for me. I want to display single posts of a custom post type (portfolio) each in its own div. I don't want any duplicate posts on the page. I need 13 different divs, each containing info about a different post. Link to the page in question: http://ww3.gbs-inc.com/featured-projects/

```
<div class="port1">
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio&showposts=1' );
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div class="port2">
    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div class="port3">
    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to execute the query in each individual div instead of looping the div within the query?

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio&showposts=13' ); 
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
$my_query->the_post();
?>
  <div class="port1">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If you want to number the divs sequentially, you can use a counter:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio&showposts=13' ); 
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
$my_query->the_post();
?>
  <div class="port<?php echo $i++; ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: your second option, using a counter, is a very cool and simple way of accomplishing this. Thanks for that! I have to style the page exactly as the client wants it so I may have to revisit this if I can't get the divs to play nicely with each other.

Comment: @PatrickMcGilvray - glad to hear. feel free to mark it as answered.